# Some irrelevant uses of German "ja"

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, particle

Some irrelevant uses of German ja:

- Emphatic particle in imperatives:

> Geht **ja** nicht in den Wald!
>
> Mach ja deine Hausaufgaben!

- In exclamative sentences:

> Das ist **ja** interessant!

My questions are:

1. Am I allowed to use "ja" whenever I want to emphasize my sentence? For example, when I want to say "the world is **really** unjust",  "Die Welt is **ja** ungerecht" has exactly the same meaning?
2. Is it rude to use "ja" in imperative form? does it have negative connotation?

Comment: IMHO, "ja" is used as a *Modalpartikel (der)* in the cases you describe.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Do you mean to say it is "_der_ Modalpartikel"? As I learnt on this site, it's "_die_ Partikel".

Comment: @Vogt Ah... I always say der Partikel, but some others say die Partikel. I don't know which one of those two is "correct".

Comment: @FUZxxl (please [use @Hendrik to notify me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)): And some say _das Partikel_ `:-)`

Comment: @Hendrik Sorry, I skipped the first part of your name by accident. It's like die / der / das *Nutella*... :)

Comment: @FUZxxl, @Hendrik (I know I can't address both in one comment): The gender of _Partikel_ was brought up in another comment discussion somewhere. Seems like a physical particle is [das or die](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Partikel_Teilchen) while a linguistic particle always is [die Partikel](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Partikel_Wort_Reliquie). No idea what _der Partikel_ means :)

Comment: @Tim IMHO der Partikel is the physical meaning of a particle.

Comment: "die Partikel" is the plural of "der Partikel" (aka "das Partikelchen" since particles are usually small ("Teil*chen*"))  ;-)

Comment: This an similar questions have been asked several times (search for 'ja'), Maybe a motivated mod could unify the questions into a single 'What's the meaning/semantics/usage of *ja*?'-post? Just a suggestion :)

Comment: Related Question: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/12228/1487

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. The role of "ja" is less of emphasis
   than of surprise: "Wusstest du, dass
   Tom in seiner Jugend einer der
   besten Schachspieler Deutschlands
   war?" "Das ist ja interessant!".

   It is also often used to express
   irony, for example if someone shares
   some gossip that you really don't
   care about, you could say (in a
   slightly bored manner) "Das ist ja
   interessant!"

   In your example it would probably be
   better to say "Die Welt ist wirklich
   ungerecht!" (or more colloquially
   "Die Welt ist echt ungerecht!").
2. This form often comes across as rude
   and patronizing. Even when used by
   adults towards children it makes the
   adult come across as fairly upset.
   It's probably better to avoid it
   altogether, except in fictional
   writing. More polite alternatives
   would be:

   > Geht bitte nicht in den Wald.
   >
   > Mach bitte deine Hausaufgaben.

Comment: "Leg den Schlagstock jetzt bitte weg, ja?" ;-)

Comment: Well, I guess there's a point where politeness may not be the goal ;)

Comment: "Sven-Oliver, hör jetzt bitte auf den fremden Mann zu treten" (with apologies to anyone here actually named S-O ;D)

Comment: Die Überraschung liegt im *interessant*, nicht im *ja*. Das Ja unterstreicht lediglich. Ebenso unterstreicht es die Ironie, es stellt sie nicht selbst her. Und es unterstreicht auch nur einen Befehl oder eine Anweisung, die auch ohne Ja grob und unhöflich sein können.

Answer (score 5):

The discourse particle *ja* is normally used to signal that the other person already knows what you say, that is, it's part of the common ground. As such, it is, in it's 'basic' use, roughly equivalent to *as you know*. As such, it can't be used in the following sentence

> DONT: Ich muss dir unbedingt was sagen: Ich liebe dich **ja**! (lit. *I have to tell you something: As you know, I love you!*)

However, it can be used to backround information that you believe is known to the person you're talking to:

> DO: Ich muss dir unbedingt was sagen: Ich liebe dich ja, und deswegen will ich dich als Erben eintragen. (lit. *I have to tell you something: As you know, I love you, and so I decided to make you my heir*)

Even in 'surprise contexts' it is necessary for the other person to already know the information, so, you can only express that *you yourself* are surprised by some information, but *ja* cannot express that it should be surprising to the other person that something is surprising. Again a nice example

> DONT: [As a gynecologist you inspect a person and say] Sie sind **ja** schwanger! (*You are pregnant, and that is something you already know but I find it surprising!*)
>
> DO: [As a person finding the positive pregnancy test of the person s_he is living with] Du bist **ja** schwanger! (*You are pregnant, and I didnt know that before!*)

Note that *ja* does not bear any positive or negative connotations. It's a very useful German word for structuring discourse, I'd definitely recommend using it. It let's you tell somebody something without sounding overly patronizing in case the person already knows this information.

## This answer is based on the following thesis:

Bárány, A. (2009). Form and interpretation of the German discourse particles ja, doch and wohl. Diploma thesis. Available from: http://othes.univie.ac.at/7532.

Comment: Das Gynäkologenbeispiel verstehe ich nicht. Wieso soll er nicht sagen "Sie sind ja schwanger!", wenn er es bemerkt und annimmt, dass die Frau es schon weiß?

Comment: Regarding the gynecologist: You see, you have to coerce quite a lot to come up with a context that fits the use of *ja*. I simply had another context in mind, where the pregnant person does not know of his_her pregnancy and visited the doctor to know what's up with her_him. The gist is, that it *does not* make sense, which is why *ja* cannot be used in this situation. That is what the big DONT in front of the sentence is supposed to point out :3

Comment: I can't follow. You wrote: "You are pregnant, and that is something you already know but I find it surprising!". Speak the sentence with the Ja, and then repeat it in the same intonation, just without the Ja, and tell me, whether the meaning changes meanwhile.

Comment: The truth conditions don't change if that's what you're after. Sorry, I don't really get where you're getting from either :)

Comment: In your citation box, you write DON'T, then give an example, then explain, that the context should be, that the doctor is surprised but the pregnant woman is not. In the second comment you write, the pregnant woman does not know of her (his?) pregnancy. That doesn't match. It's unclear what you try to tell.

Comment: @userunknown A gynecologist should not usually be terribly surprised when one of their patients is pregnant. The usual situation at the gynecologist's would be that the doctor is communicating the results of a pregnancy test to the patient. And in that situation, "Sie sind ja schwanger!" does not make sense. Therefore, "DON'T".

Comment: I'd say that "ja" in imperative sentences like "Tu das ja nicht" is an entirely different word with a different meaning; the discourse particle you described is unstressed, but the one in imperative sentences is stressed.

Comment: @wolfgang: Was Du oder asiakr mit dem Beispiel verbinden entzieht sich meiner Kenntnis. Dass der Arzt überrascht ist, ist nach meiner Lesart des Kommentars die Prämisse der Situation. Die Frau weiß es schon. Diese Lesart ist konsistent mit den anderen Beispielen und Kommentaren dazu. Die Frau kann sehr jung sein, sehr alt sein, vom Arzt ein Diaphragma eingesetzt bekommen haben - wieso soll der Arzt nicht überrascht sein können?

Comment: @user Über die *Bedeutung* des Satzes herrscht Einigkeit. Das Beispiel wurde wahrscheinlich gewählt, weil der Gynäkologe sich in solchen Dingen eben keine Überraschung erlauben/anmerken lassen sollte. Und wenn's jetzt noch nicht klar ist, dann ist es nur Haarspalterei: sicher könnte man die genaue Situation in ein oder zwei Absätzen genauer schildern.

Comment: @wolfgang: Das ist auch nicht schlüssig. Abgesehen davon, dass kaum Gynäkologen hier hinsurfen, um sich vorschreiben zu lassen, ob sie sich Überraschung anmerken lassen sollen: Wieso denn nicht? Um als Halbgott in Weiß zu imponieren? Haben wir schon wieder 1950? Man wünscht sich doch offene Ärzte denen man vertrauen kann, keine verhinderten Burgschauspieler.

Comment: That escalated quicky.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on whether you are on **du** or on **Sie**.

I would only use it in context of **Sie**, if I want to be offensive

> Kommen Sie mir ja nicht blöd.

But I find noting wrong in forbidding a child to go alone into the wood

> Geh ja nicht in den Wald!

or to caution my coworkers

> Mach ja eine Sicherung von deinen Daten.

Comment: Das konnte ich ja nicht wissen. Das hat ja nicht die Welt gekostet. Es ist ja noch Zeit. - Nur mit *Du*?

Answer (score -1):

> Some irrelevant uses of German ja:
>
> Emphatic particle in imperatives:
>   Geht ja nicht in den Wald!
>   Mach ja deine Hausaufgaben!
>
> In exclamative sentences:
>   Das ist ja interessant!

In my opinion those usages are not irrelevant.

The `"Emphatic particle"` in those two examples turns the nature of the sentence into a threat rather than a pure instruction / command:

Mach ja deine Hausaufgaben [sonst setzt es was]!

The part in brackets is left out when spoken, but it's always implied (the actual implication will be based on the context, this is just an example).

Basically the *ja* shows that there will be consequences if the instruction is not followed in those cases.

In `"exclamative sentences"` or rather in your specific example the *ja* implies irony and turns the meaning of the sentence into "Das ist total langweilig". This is a common response to "fun" (irony!) factoids and the like.

So to your questions:

Are you allowed to use "ja" whenever you want to emphasize your sentence? No! Apart from the two cases above there are many more where "ja" changes the meaning of a sentence or implies something. You should only use it if you are aware of what it implies.

Is it rude to use "ja" in imperative form? Yes! In most cases it is, because it changes your statement into a threat.

Comment: "Mach deine Hausaufgaben [sonst setzt es was]!" funktioniert auch ohne *ja*. Deine Ergänzung ist reine Willkür. Dass der Satz ohne Ja keine Drohung ist, ist Ansichtssache, ebenso, dass er durch das Ja zu einer wird. Ebenso bestreite ich, dass das Ja in der 3. Zeile den Satz ins ironische ändert. Der Satz kann ironisch sein, muss aber nicht, und kann auch ohne Ja ironisch gemeint sein und verstanden werden.