# How can I translate the adverb "doch" in sentences?

Tags: translation, adverb, modal-particle

What is the difference between "Dann mach *doch* das Fenster zu" and "Dann mach das Fenster zu"?
Further examples:

> Ich fahre doch nur 90.
>   Sieh doch im Korb nach.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Die deutsche Sprache enthält eine Wortart, die es in der englischen **gar** nicht gibt, und die in anderen Sprachen auch nur selten zu finden ist:

### Modalpartikel

(Das fett hervorgehobene »gar« im ersten Satz ist eine Modalpartikel.)

Sie heißen auch »Abtönungspartikeln« und jeder Übersetzer hasst sie wie die Pest, weil es keine Möglichkeit gibt, sie halbwegs korrekt ins Englische übersetzen. Meist lässt man sie beim Übersetzen von Deutsch nach Englisch einfach weg. Beim Übersetzen vom Englischen ins Deutsche fügt man **aber** normalerweise keine Modalpartikeln ein, weil sie im Original **ja gar** nicht vorhanden sind. (Die fett hervorgehobenen Wörter »aber«, »ja« und »gar« im letzten Satz sind weitere Beispiele.) Wenn man einen deutschen Satz ins Englische übersetzt, und diesen englischen danach ins Deutsche zurück übersetzt, verschwinden üblicherweise alle Modalpartikeln.

Deutsch ist eine Sprache, die sehr exzessiven Gebrauch von dieser Wortart macht. Ein paar Beispiele:

> Das ging **aber** schnell!
>   Das muss er **ja** gesehen haben.
>   Was ist **denn** das?
>   Dann sieh **doch** selber nach!
>   Walter kann **gar** nichts dafür.

Mehr Beispiele findet man hier: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modalpartikel

Modalpartikeln ändern die Aussage eines Satzes nicht. Sie modifizieren nur die Stimmung, die mit der Aussage mit-transportiert wird. Modalpartikeln drücken Überraschung, Empörung, Ungeduld und andere Stimmungen aus.

Diese Wortart ist auch schwer zu definieren, weil jede Modalpartikel ein Homonym in einer anderen Wortart hat. Anders formuliert: Bestimmte Wörter aus »gewöhnlichen« Wortarten können in bestimmten Fällen als Modalpartikel verwendet werden.

In den in der Frage genannten Beispielen hat das Wort »doch« immer die Funktion einer Modalpartikel:

> Dann mach **doch** das Fenster zu.
>   Ich fahre **doch** nur 90.
>   Sieh **doch** im Korb nach.

Wer als englischer Muttersprachler Deutsch als Fremdsprache lernt, hat meist beträchtliche Schwierigkeiten, den Sinn dieser Wörter zu verstehen, da es diese Wörter in der eigenen Muttersprache **ja gar** nicht gibt.

Umgekehrt haben auch Menschen mit Deutsch als Muttersprache, die Englisch lernen wollen, Probleme mit diesen Wörtern. Bobby übersetzte in seiner Antwort beispielsweise den Satz

> Dann mach doch das Fenster zu.

mit »Well, *already* close the window.« Das »already« ist hier falsch. Die beste Übersetzung ist noch immer die, bei der die Modalpartikel weggelassen wird:

> Then close the window.

Allerdings geht dabei der Ausdruck der Ungeduld verloren.

Comment: Wow, great answer! I'd never read a structured explanation of this. <snark>That's one of the reasons why "wörtliche Übersetzung" sucks.</snark>

Comment: "Close the window already" würde ich nicht falsch nennen. Es transportiert die Ungeduld. Natürlich ist es nicht perfekt. Es ist zu explizit. Wie "Nun mach schon das Fenster zu!". In jedem Falle eine großartige Antwort!

Comment: I'm hesitant to disagree completely since I am not a language scholar, but I have observed the use of "indeed" (more often by British speakers, less so by Americans) in the same context and even similar sentence placement. I am _not_ suggesting a one-to-one translation in all cases, but as I perceive it can express the same idea and attitude. Take the single-word response (think up your own preceding statement):  "Doch!" --> "Indeed!"  It is tempting to assign a dictionary definition to indeed and then say "that's not what 'doch' means", but just like doch, indeed can assume undefined subtly.

Comment: This category of words exists also in Russian with many examples.

Comment: Gerade das als erstes Beispiel genannte *gar (nicht)* lässt sich aber üblicherweise recht treffend als *not ... at all* ins Englische übertragen.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Das liegt daran, dass das Englische *Modaladverbien* als Ersatz für die nicht vorhandenen Partikeln verwendet und im Beispiel, das Hubert gewählt hat, *gar* gar keine Partikel ist, sondern, zumindestens nach Ansicht des Duden (und mir) in diesem Fall ein Adverb  (*gar zu selten* z.B. ist eine Partikel, *gar nicht* eben nicht, Beweis: *ganz und gar nicht*).

Comment: it's not a literal translation, but I think sentences using doch can be translated to convey the sense better than just skipping it. Dann mach doch das Fenster zu: Then why don't you close.the window. Ich fahre doch nur 90: But I'm only going at 90. Sieh doch im Korb nach: Why don't you look in the basket.

Answer (score 8):

You should be aware that such an extensions with `doch` is not necessarily positive. Be aware that I'm from Austria, so that might be a small cultural difference here to somewhere else or only my personal experience/view. Consider the following example:

> Es zieht und mir ist kalt!
>
> It's cold and there's a terrible draft!

There are now two responses:

> Dann mach das Fenster zu.
>
> Then close the window.

This is an appraisal and a suggestion.

> Dann mach doch das Fenster zu.
>
> Well, close the window already.

I'm not sure about this translation, so please let me explain. The `doch` in this context, together with an irritated and/or uninterested tone, can have the meaning of "why do you bother me with this if you can fix it yourself?". Similar example:

> Dann mach was du willst!
>
> Dann mach doch was du willst!

At least for me the `doch` adds a sense of "if you ain't gonna listen to me then leave me alone" in this context and adds a slightly offended tone to it. Be aware that this is *extremely* based on context and tone of the voice.

Make sure to check out all the examples [on the german Wiktionary page on `doch`](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/doch).

Comment: Regarding `Well, (already) close the window.` -- Changing the word order improves the translation and I think carries with it the same tone: `Then close the window already.`  The same idea as doch is often carried in the tone rather than a word addition:  `Well, close the window.` expressed with a sharp or snappy intonation and/or a subtle pause after "Well".

Answer (score 8):

`doch` in your examples indicates that this is part of an argument between two people.

The reply includes `doch` to indicate irritation and/or disagreement.

e.g.

- passenger says: drive slower

  driver responds: 
    `"Ich fahre doch nur 90"` / `"But I'm only driving 90"`

  (in this case `doch` indicates disagreement)
- someone says" "where is my sweater?"

  response: `"sieh doch im Korb nach"` / `"Why don't you look in the basket?"`

  (in this case `doch` indicates irritation)
- `"Dann mach doch das Fenster zu"` / `"if that bothers you, then close the window?"` (irritation)
  vs. 
  `"Dann mach das Fenster zu"` / `"then close the window"`

Comment: I don't think your translations faithfully carry over the tone.

Comment: dude, I'm German

Comment: What about "Just look in the basket" and "Then just close the window!". ISTM that, depending on how "doch" is used, translations using "just", "but" or "however" (among a few other alternatives) work quite nicely. I don't think that turning a sentence into a question using "Why" conveys the meaning as well as it should.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the meaning of *doch* you are looking for, is the one you can find in [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/doch), where it's explained as:

> (*doch*) macht aus einem Befehlsatz einen Vorschlag

For instance

> Nehmen Sie (*doch*) Platz!

Depending on the tone, this imperative without *doch* sounds like an order. The presence of *doch* transforms this order into a suggestion.

(Maybe *doch* is there to tell you "oh, you were waiting for me to tell you to take a seat, but please feel free to go ahead, 'cause anyway it's expected that you do it, make yourself at home!" instead of "sit down!". Anyway, this is only *my* interpretation of why *doch* is there.)

Comment: That is not true "Sei doch mal still!" is not a suggestion. It is an order. The suggestion/order distinction is brought in by tone, not by "doch"

Comment: @Emanuel Mh, I was rather thinking *doch* there is like in *nehmen Sie doch Platz*. Set a constant tone (say neutral, whatever that means) and repeat that with and without *doch*. I did that and *then*, I thought I had understood what Wiktionary said. Anyway I cannot erase the answer, since it has the checkmark.

Comment: This particular example sounds like a suggestion because it's just known that way. Maybe you could just edit the answer and add that "doch" can soften it to the point that it sounds like a suggestion but it does depend on tone.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult :) doch in this case is used to strengthen and reinforce your sentence. There is not all much difference between your two sentences; perhaps you could say something like "so *do* close the windows, then" for your second example.

Answer (score 1):

Generally dictionaries can't handle "Modalpartikel", special function words that convey additional information about the mode in which the speaker means his utterance. The various uses of a modal particles can only be clarified separately by giving an example sentence and a description as to what information the modal particle conveys. The various modalities can be friendliness, irritation or annoyance, contradiction, logical consequence etc etc.

It would be a study of its own to find out what modalities these modal particles can express. Dictionaries have not yet found out how to handle modal particles. In any case, they would need a lot of more space.

If you check modal particles in dictionaries you will find that the entries are insufficient and that only 10 or 20 per cent of the uses are covered. Analyses of the modalities are lacking.

So translating modalities from German to English is a tricky problem. There is almost never a 1 to 1 relation.  Sometimes there is a corresponding word, but very often the same modality is expressed totally different.

So I would translate "Das ist ja nicht wahr" with "That's a lie!".

Wiktionary tries to give an overview of the function word doch
http://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/doch