# When to use the word "mal"? How does it change the meaning?

Tags: adverb, modal-particle

When do we use the word *mal* after a verb? Does it change the meaning?
For example: what is the difference between the following sentences.

> Guck mal. Frag mal.
>   Guck. Frag.

Comment: Similar [question](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/23303/1696).

Answer (score 17):

The addition of the word 'mal' does not *directly* change the meaning in this context. It does, however, change the underlying tone of the statement.

A sentence like

> Frag mal dort nach.

makes your statement more of a proposition while

> Frag dort nach.

sounds more like a direct instruction.

This is the reason why the configuration Verb+'mal' is more used in an informal context. For example, if a student asks another a question during classes, he would answer:

> Weiß nicht. Frag mal den Lehrer.

Without the 'mal' this would sound distant and maybe a bit annoyed.

In contrast, the word 'mal' is usually avoided in very formal situations where you tend to distance yourself from the converstational partner for politeness:

> Für weitere Informationen fragen Sie Herrn XY.

So in conclusion if you speak with a friend or someone you know well, always use the 'mal'. If you want to be polite (for example in official correspondence), try to avoid it as much as possible.

Comment: Is "frag mal dort nach" the same as "du solltest dort nachfragen"?

Comment: @Deni Basically. It is somewhat more colloquial, however.

Comment: @Chieron But it is closer to "du solltest..." than to "frag dort nach", right?

Comment: @Deni Yes. *solltest* strongly implies a suggestion (more so than the *mal*-construction), the imperative an order or annoyance. *mal* tends to be seen as an abbreviation of *einmal* (see Hubert's answer, which is wrong in this case), and thus more informal.

Comment: Actually I feel it the opposite: "Solltest" is in my view a very decisive suggestion ("it is really a good idea to do that") while "mal" I think is more an idea suggestion ("it might be a good idea to do that"). So unless I misunderstood your English (quite possible), I'd say "mal" more strongly implies a suggestion than "solltest".

Comment: @celtschk I don't really agree with that. It could be situational but in all cases I can think of *solltest* is less decisive than *mal*. Examples would be "Geh mal schlafen!" and "Du solltest schlafen." . Here the first sentence is much more decisive to me than the second one. There can be situations where irony and a "I already said that a thousand times" context play a role where it is the other way round. But I think in most cases *solltest* is less decisive

Comment: @RainbowRevenge: In *my* feeling, "Du solltest schlafen!" is more decisive than "Geh mal schlafen."

Answer (score 1):

"Guck" and "frag" are imperative forms of their respective verbs. That is to say that they are *commands.*

The term "mal" is a "softener" in this context. When placed behind commands like "guck" and "frag" as "guck mal," and "frag mal," it turns those commands into *suggestions.*

The effect of "mal" is more or less the opposite of "doch" (the latter is used for emphasis, the former for **de** emphasis.)

Comment: So "guck doch mal" is an oxymoron? ;-)

Comment: @celtschk :I'd say so.

Comment: I think the combination 'doch mal' expresses something that might be spelt out in English as 'for once (mal), why don't you (doch)'. Not that easy to nail down to one single meaning, these modal particles.