# What does "doch sicher" mean?

Tags: meaning, modal-particle

I know that *doch* means *surely* and *sicher* means *sure*. Could you please explain more about the collocation *doch sicher* in the following example?
What exactly does *doch sicher* mean?

> Sabine, du kennst doch sicher den Rudi?

Comment: "Sarah, you already know Rudi, right?"

Comment: @KilianFoth There's nothing in the sentence that would translate to "already", IMHO

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Your duplicate refers to non-interrogative sentences. The meaning of "doch" is slightly different there.

Comment: @KilianFoth: »Sarah, you **already** know Rudi, right?« ist auf Deutsch aber: »Sarah, du kennt Rudi **bereits**, nicht wahr?«. Das Wort »doch« ist in diesem Fall eine Modalpartikel, die im Deutschen sehr häufig, im Englischen hingegen gar nicht zu finden sind. Siehe: http://german.stackexchange.com/a/12242/1487

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Doch* does actually **not** mean "surely" in this context. It *strengthens* the emphasis on the "sicher" here which is something different.

> Du kennst sicher den Rudi?

Would mean very much the same thing without the *doch* -

> You surely know Rudi?

*Doch* is a particle that can be added to interrogative sentences to express (1) a hope for confirmation or express (2) you mean to know the answer, but it escapes you for the moment.

> (1) Du kennst doch bestimmt Rudi?

Definitely asks for a "yes" as an answer, implies you expect he knows Rudi. Note the *doch* can go with adverbs other than *sicher*.

> (2) Wie heißt dein Freund aus München doch gleich?

Expresses "I'm meant to know it, but can't come up with that name for the moment."

*Doch* and *sicher* are not a pair here - *doch* can be used with other words in questions as well, see my examples.

In non-interrogative sentences, the particle *doch* can have slightly different meanings, typically putting emphasis on a statement - but you should be able to look that up in a good dictionary.

Comment: Of course in (2) the "gleich" has basically the same function: You are not interested in what the friend's name will be *soon* but just what it is.

Comment: No, it hasn't. The sentence does not imply the friend's name is going to be different at all anytime soon. It says "I should know what his name is, but cannot recall at the moment"