# „Was ist bitte daran hübsch?“ – Funktion von „bitte“

Tags: meaning-in-context, politeness, modal-particle

Ich verfolge in einem anderen Forum einen Shitstorm, der mit der Frage „Was ist *bitte* daran hübsch?“ unter einem Bild startet.

Im Laufe der Diskussion hat sich jetzt rausgestellt,  dass der Poster eine neutrale, höfliche (deswegen mit *bitte*) Frage stellen wollte. Allerdings empfinden im Forum alle außer ihm die Frage als unverschämt und wertend.

Warum wirkt hier der Satz ohne *bitte* neutral und der Satz mit *bitte* unhöflich?

Comment: Für mich ist die Variante mit "bitte" nicht notwendigerweise unhöflich, aber sie macht klar, dass der Frager anderer Meinung ist. Ohne "bitte" kann es entweder neutral sein, oder (mündlich je nach Tonfall) ebenfalls ausdrücken, dass der Frager anderer Meinung ist. Einen Shitstorm auslösen sollte beides nicht, aber das ist halt das Internet ...

Comment: "Bitte" kann hier prinzipiell zwei Dinge vermitteln. Das in meinen Augen wahrscheinlichere ist, dass der Fragesteller nicht die Meinung teilt und in abwertender Form eine Rechtfertigung ersucht. Ich würde wahrscheinlich dann sogar sagen: "Was ist denn bitte schön daran hübsch?". Die andere, hier unwahrscheinlichere, Interpretation ist, dass einfach der Wunsch nach Wiederholung / Klarstellung ersucht wird, weil es nicht verstanden wurde. Jedenfalls bräuchte man Intonation um dies klar zu unterscheiden können. — Interessant wäre vielleicht, ob der Fragesteller Muttersprachler ist.

Comment: @Em1, Der Fragesteller ist meines Wissens Muttersprachler.

Comment: 'bitte' is one of those elusive *Abtönungspartikel* peculiar to German. Literally it marks a polite question, but it has been used ironically so often that it's now considered rude - just like e.g. "gefälligst", only not quite as much.

Comment: Für mich klingt es nicht unhöflich, aber leicht indigniert.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Im Internet gilt gemeinhin die Regel *assume good faith*, an die man sich auch hier halten könnte. Nehmen wir den Satz »Was ist daran hübsch?«, denn dieser kann auf mindestens zwei Arten verstanden werden:

- > Nun ja, ich sehe dieses Bild, das viele Leute »hübsch« nennen. Für mich wirkt es aber nur wie blaue und rote Farbsprenkel auf einer Leinwand. Ich gehe davon aus, dass die Leute, die »hübsch« sagen, Recht haben, möchte aber wissen, *warum* sie es sagen. (genuine Neugierde)
- > Aha, es gibt Leute, die dieses Bild »hübsch« nennen. Diese Leute haben offensichlich einen Knick in der Optik. Was soll denn an diesem Bild, das ja nur aus blauen und roten Farbsprenkeln besteht, hübsch sein?

*Assume good faith* verlangt, dass wir die erste Bedeutung verstehen, denn es ist möglich (vielleicht sogar wahrscheinlich), dass diese Bedeutung gemeint war.

Was verändert das Wörtchen *bitte* an diesem Satz?
Nun, man kennt es in verschiedenen Funktionen:

1. Als Bestandteil einer Bitte

   > Gibst du mir *bitte* die Milch?
2. Als Antwort auf einen Dank

   > Danke für die Auskunft!
   >   *Bitte*, keine Ursache!
3. Als kurz gefasste, höfliche Aufforderung zum Eintreten, um etwas zu wiederholen etc.

   > *Bitte*, treten Sie näher!
   >
   > *Bitte*?
4. Als Verstärkungspartikl

   > Wie hast du denn das *bitte* geschafft?

Wahrscheinlich, so wie du die Ereignisse beschreibst, wollte der Verfasser des ursprünglichen Posts die erste Bedeutung verwenden. Das funktioniert aber syntaktisch nicht. Das höfliche *bitte* in *darf ich bitte* kann nur in einer Entscheidungsfrage auftauchen. Gestellt wurde aber eine Ergänzungsfrage (»Was …?«). In dieser wirkt *bitte* aber nur in der vierten aufgeführten Bedeutung, als Verstärkungspartikel. Und wenn es verstärkt, muss vorher eine dezidierte Meinung vorhanden gewesen sein (denn Nachfragen lässt sich nicht höflich verstärken). Man möge anhand der folgenden Sätze selbst überprüfen, welche man für höfliche Bitten hält und welche nicht:

> Unterschrieben Sie bitte hier?
>
> Warum unternehmen Sie bitte nichts?
>
> Würden Sie mir bitte sagen, was ich vergessen habe?
>
> Was habe ich bitte vergessen?

Leider funktioniert in diesem Fall auch *assume good faith* nicht mehr, denn die Frage ist nicht mehr als höflich zu verstehen.

Und wie lässt sich das Problem beheben? Nun, indem die Ergänzungsfrage, wie in einem der Beispiele, zu einer (erweiterten) Entscheidungsfrage umformuliert wird:

> Sagt ihr mir bitte, was daran hübsch ist?

Comment: "Sagt ihr mir bitte, was daran hübsch ist?" ist für mich eindeutig höflich, Aber wie ist das bei "Bitte sagt mir, was daran hübsch sein soll?". Ist das immer noch höflich, auch wenn ich dabei klar mache, dass ich anderer Meinung bin?

Comment: @Iris das ist ein schwieriger Grenzfall, weil »sein soll« schon eine Wertung impliziert. Ich würde als Mod bei sowas wahrscheinlich beide Seiten zur Ordnung rufen. Man kann durch das entsprechende Äußere die Wortwahl nur bedingt kaschieren …

Answer (score 2):

Den Satz *Was ist daran hübsch?* kann man im genannten Kontext (Internetforum, Diskussion über ein Bild) als Wertung verstehen, wenn man zu dem auf dem Bild gezeigten Motiv eine emotionale Bindung hat. Das wird sogar häufig der Fall sein.

Beispiel: Das Foto habe ich im Urlaub aufgenommen und es gefällt mir besonders gut, oder es zeigt einen Freund/Angehörigen.

Das Problem am geschriebenen Wort ist eben das Transportieren des gewünschten Tonfalls. Als Leser kann man häufig nicht wissen, ob der Tonfall höhnisch oder fragend-neutral gewesen wäre, wenn der Satz gesprochen worden wäre.

Aufgrund der unterstellten emotionalen Bindung zum gezeigten Motiv werden Leser dann häufig einen höhnischen Unterton "reinlesen" und den Satz verstehen als

> Was? Du findest das hübsch? Spinnst Du?

In diesem Fall jedoch wird die Frage durch das eingefügte *bitte* nicht höflicher. Im Gegenteil fügt das *bitte* der ohnehin schon als höhnisch empfundenen Frage eine weitere Verstärkung der spöttischen Herablassung hinzu.

Es ist eventuell eine Kurzfassung von

> Ich bitte Euch! Was ist daran hübsch?
>   Ob bitte! Was ist daran hübsch?
>   Was, bitteschön, ist daran hübsch?

Wie lucas.coenig in den Kommentaren bereits sagte, gibt es auch weitere solche Einschübe, die eventuell den Charakter der Aussage noch deutlicher herausstellen.

> Was **zum Geier** ist daran hübsch?
>   Was **zum Teufel** ist daran hübsch?
>   Was **verdammt noch mal** ist daran hübsch?
>   Was **zur Hölle** ist daran hübsch?
>   ...

Zu der Frage

> Warum wirkt hier der Satz ohne bitte neutral und der Satz mit bitte unhöflich?

Das *bitte* hat damit aus meiner Sicht nichts zu tun. Menschen, die den Satz ohnehin als neutral empfunden hätten, würden das *bitte* entweder als höflicher erachten oder die Gefahr sehen, dass der Satz (ab-)wertend verstanden werden könnte. Sie würden aber trotzdem die Frage beantworten.

Menschen, die den Satz aber ohnehin als höhnische, rhetorische Frage verstehen, werden sich durch das *bitte* nur noch mehr von oben herab behandelt fühlen und die ganze Diskussion auf einer emotionalen Ebene fortführen.

Herr [Schulz von Thun](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vier-Seiten-Modell) hat eben Recht...

Comment: Doch, ich finde schon, dass das "bitte" eine zusätzliche Verschärfung der Herablassung (so denn eine gewollt war) bewirkt. Dabei ist "bitte" einer von mehreren Einschüben, die das bewirken können (mit der ursprünglich höflich gemeinten Version des Wortes hat das nichts mehr zu tun). Ähnlich würde bspw. wirken: "Was ist daran *in Gottes Namen* hübsch?" Damit soll ausgedrückt werden, dass man ganz und gar anderer Meinung ist und die Frage nur rhetorisch meint.

Comment: Moment, ich glaube, Du hast falsch verstanden was ich meine :-) Ich habe gesagt, dass ein Satz wie "Was ist daran hübsch?" je nach Kontext unverschämt empfunden werden kann oder auch nicht. **Das** ist unabhängig von dem "Bitte", denn das "Bitte" ist in diesem Fall keine Höflichkeitsfloskel. **Wenn** der Satz aber als unverschämt empfunden wird, dann verstärkt das "Bitte" noch den unverschämten Character durch das Hinzufügen eines herablassenden Tonfalls.

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar: Jupp, so sehe ich das auch. Ich wollte aber auch hinzufügen, dass "bitte" nicht der einzige Einschub ist, der das bewirkt. Andere Einschübe können ganz anders aussehen und trotzdem eine ähnlichen Funktion erfüllen. Ich weiß nicht, wie das entstanden ist, aber es ist schon interessant, wie "bitte" hier ganz anders interpretiert wird als klassischerweise.

Comment: Ohne "bitte" sehe ich null Wertung in dem Satz. Ich habe das jetzt nicht verstanden, kannst du nochmal erklären, was daran hübsch ist. -> "Was ist daran hübsch?" Intonation spielt dabei aber eine entscheidende Rolle.

Comment: Das "bitte" hat hier so eine "kann mir einer das mal BITTE erklären - aber ich glaube ja nicht, dass es einer kann, denn es ist ja völliger Unfug"-Bedeutung. "BITTE erklärt es mir. Vielleicht bin ich ja zu dumm. Aber da ich nicht zu dumm bin, müssen die anderen zu dumm sein."

Comment: @userunknown Stimmt, aber auch das hat nichts mit dem "Unverschämtheitsgrad" zu tun. Wertend ist der Satz auf jeden Fall, da er auf einer persönlichen Meinung basiert.

Comment: @em1 Wenn Du fragst "Ich habe das jetzt nicht verstanden, kannst Du nochmal erklären, was daran hübsch ist?" implizierst Du, dass *Du* die Merkmale für "hübsch" in einer Sachte nicht erkennen kannst, die jemand anders (der Gefragte) aber erkennen kann. Das heißt, ihr habt über den "Hübscheitsgrad" eine unterschiedliche Meinung. Und damit ist auch eine Wertung impliziert. Du hättest die Sache/Person eventuell nicht als hübsch klassifiziert, der andere aber schon.

Comment: @userunknown Dann hoffe ich, dass meine bearbeitete Antwort eher Deinen Gefallen findet.

Comment: Ich verstehe (siehe meine Antwort) den Satz ohne *bitte* durchaus als höfliche Frage. Mit *bitte* (siehe ebenfalls meine Antwort) geht diese Verständnismöglichkeit aber verloren.

Answer (score 1):

Das Wort »bitte« in diesem Satz ist eine Modalpartikel, auch Abtönungpartikel genannt. Ich habe diese Wortart in einer [Antwort auf eine andere Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/12242/1487) bereits ausführlich behandelt.

Hier das Wichtigste:

1. Ausnahmslos alle Modalpartikel, die es in der deutschen Sprache gibt, sind Homonyme von Wörtern, die anderen Wortarten angehören. Das macht es mitunter schwierig, Modalpartikel in einem Satz zu identifizieren, weil man sie auf den ersten Blick für Adverbien, Adjektive, Konjunktionen usw. hält.
   Wenn man also in einem Satz auf ein Wort trifft, dass einer Wortart anzugehören scheint, die an dieser Stelle eigentlich nicht passt, dann sollte man in Betracht zeihen, dass man es stattdessen mit einer Modalpartikel zu tun hat.
2. Wenn man sämtliche Modalpartikel aus einem korrekten deutschen Satz ersatzlos herausstreicht, bleibt ein völlig korrekter deutscher Satz übrig. Dieser kürzere Satz transportiert aber weiterhin im Wesentlichen die gleiche Aussage wie der ursprüngliche Satz, jedoch mit weniger Emotionen.
   Wenn man also ein Wort weglassen kann, ohne dass sich die grundlegende Bedeutung des Satzes ändert, dann ist das ein starkes Indiz für eine Modalpartikel.
3. Die Modalpartikel tönen die Bedeutung des Satzes ab. Das heißt: Sie verändern nicht die grundlegende Bedeutung, aber eine Modalpartikel kann dem Satz eine gewisse Emotion hinzufügen und somit der Bedeutung eine gewisse emotionale Färbung verleihen.
   Trifft man also auf ein Wort, dessen Fehlen die Grundaussage nicht verändern würde, das aber der Aussage eine gewisse Emotion verleiht, dann handelt es sich um eine Modalpartikel.
4. Die deutsche Sprache macht ausgiebig Gebrauch von dieser Wortart; in den meisten anderen Sprachen der Welt kommen Modalpartikel gar nicht (z.B. Englisch) oder viel seltener vor.
   Wer Englisch beherrscht, kann daher auch ein weiteres Kriterium nutzen: Wenn sich ein Wort in einem konkreten Satz 1:1 mit derselben Funktion ins Englische übersetzen lässt, ist es keine Modalpartikel. Modalpartikel wehren sich nämlich äußerst hartnäckig gegen eine wörtliche Übersetzung.

Beispiele:

> Du hast nichts an. (Feststellung einer Tatsache)
>   Du hast **ja gar** nichts an. (Verwunderung oder Empörung)
>
> Das ging schnell. (Feststellung einer Tatsache)
>   Das ging **aber** schnell. (Überraschung)
>
> Räum dein Zimmer auf. (Befehl oder Aufforderung)
>   Räum **endlich** dein Zimmer auf. (Ungeduld)
>
> Was ist daran hübsch? (Frage; Emotionslose Bitte um eine Erklärung)
>   Was ist **bitte** daran hübsch? (Widerspruch zur Behauptung daran wäre etwas hübsch)