# What is the meaning of the phrase »aber klar« and »aber klar doch«?

Tags: phrase

What is the meaning of the phrase »aber klar« and »aber klar doch«? Also, do they mean the same or do they differentiate from each other?

Thank you for answering my question :)

Comment: Both are meant to reassure the person who just asked a question, that whatever was just asked, is certainly so (or is feasible, or will be done).
The fact that the second variant includes "doch", does not change the meaning, but is just a way of adding further reassurance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both phrases mean the same. Also, only »klar« means the same, it literally means

> clearly

But you better translate it as

> surely
>   yes, of course

So, why don't the words »aber« and »doch« change the meaning? What are they good for?

Both words are modal particles. Modal particle is a word class, that is often used in German, but doesn't exist in most other languages, among them English. 
Modal particles do not change the statement of a sentence, they just add some mood or feeling to the sentence. Here in this case, both modal particles try to strengthen the meaning of »klar«.

There is no way to directly translate modal particles. Most translators just ignore them, because modal particles have no influence to the statement that is transported with the sentence. If the mood, that is encoded in the modal particles, is important, then the translator has to be creative and needs to add something to the translation.

Read more about modal particles here: [Modal Particle (in German)](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/12242/1487) or in [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_modal_particle).

Comment: wow thank you very much for that answer :)