# Translation difficulties of "Finden Sie?", "denn" and usage of "aber"

Tags: translation, german-to-english

Can't grasp the meaning of **Finden Sie** and **denn** in the following conversation.

> Brauchen Sie Hilfe?
>   Ja, bitte. Wie viel kostet denn der Tisch?
>   Der Tisch kostet 1478 Euro.
>   Das ist aber sehr teuer!
>   Finden Sie?
>   Ja. Das ist zu teuer!

Also, if I'm not mistaken, the last sentence translates to ***But, this is really expensive*** why **aber** is used before **sehr teuer**? I mean is it wrong to say:

> Aber, das ist sehr teuer!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I translate the adverb "doch" in sentences?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/12228/how-can-i-translate-the-adverb-doch-in-sentences)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The words *»denn«* and *»aber«* in

> Wie viel kostet **denn** der Tisch?
>   Das ist **aber** sehr teuer!

are modal particles (Modalpartikel), and there are [a lot of questions](https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=Modalpartikel) here on German.SE dealing with this part of speech that is rare in most other languages (among them English). German is a language, where modal particles are used very often, mainly in spoken language.

---

> Finden Sie?

is just a phrase that means

> Do you really think?

The verb *finden* does not only mean *to find*. It also can mean *to have an opinion about something*.

> Ich finde dich nett. = I like you.
>   Ich finde ihn doof. = I think he is stupid.
>   Ich finde das gar nicht gut. = I disagree.

(The word *»gar«* in the last sentence is another example for a modal particle.)

Comment: A good answer, except for the translation of “Finden Sie?”. The German phrase has an element of disbelieve/disagreement that is lost in the “What do you think?” translation. More accurate would be something like “Do you *really* think so?”

Comment: "Finden Sie?" is almost exactly the same as "You think so?"

Comment: "The verb finden does not only mean to find. It also can mean to have an opinion about something." - well, *to find* can have that meaning in English, too, although it may not be as frequently used as in German.

Answer (score -3):

In

> Wie viel kostet denn der Tisch?

ist das *denn* nur ein, für die Wahrheitsbedingungen der Aussage, überflüssiges Füllwort, ein Modalpartikel und dient dazu, eine Stimmung auszudrücken.

Durch den vorherigen Satz gewinne ich den Eindruck, dies sei der Beginn der Konversation. Besser fügt sich das *denn* bei einer Betrachtung von Alternativen ein:

```
Was kostet der Glastisch?
2000 €.
Was kostet denn ein Holztisch?
```

Es ist wohl auch im ersten Beispiel die Absicht, auszudrücken, dass die Frage nur  eine von mehreren Alternativen ist. Will man beispielsweise einen Espresso zahlen, den man eben getrunken hat, fragt man:

> Was kostet der Espresso?

Ein *denn* ist hier aber auch nicht ausgeschlossen. Das würde wiederum passen, wenn man normalerweise immer Cappuccino trinkt, von dem man den Preis schon kennt.

Das *aber* in

> Das ist aber sehr teuer!

drückt einen Tadel aus. Ohne das *aber* würde man etwa den Stolz ausdrücken, ein sehr teures Gemälde zu besitzen.

Comment: Die angesprochene Wortart heißt nicht »überflüssiges Füllwort« sondern »Modalpartikel« und war schon mehrfach Gegenstand von Fragen: https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=Modalpartikel Und Modalpartikel sind auch keineswegs überflüssig, sonder erfüllen eine wichtige semantische Funktion. Und sie sind für Deutschlernen schwierig zu verstehen, weil sie in anderen Sprachen (wie z.B. in English) so gut wie gar nicht vorkommen.

Comment: Die Tatsache, dass (Modal)partikel in der Amtssprache so gut wie gar nicht vorkommen, wirft ein geeignetes Bild darauf, wofür sie geeignet sind: Sie bringen Farbe in die Sprache.

Comment: Danke, @HubertSchölnast, habe den Fachbegriff aufgenommen und die Aussage zur Überflüssigkeit eingeschränkt.

Comment: Danke, @tofro, auch den Aspekt der Farbe habe ich versucht noch mal ausdrücklich zu benennen.